# TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype (PYTHON)

Tags: python

i want to get the max value for " TTL_TRD_QNTY" column for each symbol. The code is given below. It was working fine until one day it stopped working and gives the error message

TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Code:

```
# Group the dataframe by 'SYMBOL'
grouped = df.groupby('SYMBOL')

# Initialize an empty dataframe to store the results
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['SYMBOL', ' DATE1', ' TTL_TRD_QNTY', ' DELIV_QTY'])

# Loop through each group
for name, group in grouped:
    # Get the index of the row with the maximum 'TTQ' value for the group
    max_ttq_idx = group[' TTL_TRD_QNTY'].idxmax() #this line is resulting in error

    # Extract the row at that index and add it to the result dataframe
    result_df = result_df._append(group.loc[max_ttq_idx])
```

I tried checking the column in my excel sheet and all the rows are numbers

Comment: What is the output of `df.info()`? What is the version of Pandas? Provide a minimal reproducible example. `df.head(5).to_dict('list')`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Have you upgraded to the latest version of pandas? Which version do you use? Can you share your data?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing, "TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype," is likely due to an issue with the data type of the 'TTL_TRD_QNTY' column. To resolve this, we can make sure 'TTL_TRD_QNTY' is treated as a numeric type.

Here's a simple solution for that:

```
import pandas as pd

df[' TTL_TRD_QNTY'] = pd.to_numeric(df[' TTL_TRD_QNTY'], errors='coerce')
grouped = df.groupby('SYMBOL')
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['SYMBOL', ' DATE1', ' TTL_TRD_QNTY', ' DELIV_QTY'])

for name, group in grouped:
    group = group.dropna(subset=[' TTL_TRD_QNTY'])
    max_ttq_idx = group[' TTL_TRD_QNTY'].idxmax()
    result_df = result_df.append(group.loc[max_ttq_idx])

print(result_df)
```

This ensures that 'TTL_TRD_QNTY' is treated as numeric, handling any non-numeric values gracefully. Additionally, it checks for and removes any NaN values before finding the index with the maximum 'TTL_TRD_QNTY' to avoid potential issues with non-numeric values.

Thank you!

Comment: not working....

Comment: can you please give me some sample data to test it?